# Convergence and topology

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Please what is the classical method to answer this question, does the sequence converge in the given topology ?

1) The sequence $\big(1+(-1)^n\big)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ in $(\mathbb{R},\tau)$ such that $\tau=\{U\subset \mathbb{R},\ 0\in U\}$.

2) The sequence $\big((\frac1n,1-\frac1n,\frac{n}{n+1})\big)_{n\in\mathbb{N}^*}$ in $X=[0,1]\times[0,1]\times[0,1]$ with the usual topology in $\mathbb{R}$.

I know that: $(u_n)$ converge to $\ell$ in a topological space $E$ if $$\forall V\in \mathcal{V}_\ell,\ \exists n_0\in\mathbb{N},\ \forall n,\ n\geq n_0\Rightarrow x_n\in V
$$
 but I don't know how to apply it !

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

First you need to know what the open set looks like.

For example, the open sets in Q1 is any subset of $\mathbb{R}$ containing $0$, for example $[0,2]$ is open. Then by definition, can you find any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that every open set **containing $x$** containing tails of the sequence, hence your sequence is convergent? (ps, I think $\mathcal{T}$ you given is actually NOT a topology, you need to include $\emptyset$)

Also note the topological space is not Hausdorff, so the limit may not be unique.

> for example $\forall x= 2$ is a limit.

For Q2, it's the product topology on $X=[0,1]^3$, you can use the fact that the sequence is convergent iff each component is convergent in $[0,1]$. OR, you can directly check by the definition.

Answer (score 0):

The first sequence takes value either o 0r 2 depending on n is odd or even.clearly it can not converge other than o or 2,as you can always find an open set(take open set containing that point union 0) which will not contains points from the sequence.But this sequence can't converge to o as well as take open set[0,1)similarly sequence can not converge to 2 also.So first sequence do not converge in the given topology.

Answer (score 0):

(i) The sequence looks like: $2,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,\ldots$. A basic neighbourhood of a point $x$ is an open set (so any set that contains $0$, by definition) that also contains $x$. So clearly, every neighbourhood of $x$ contains $\{0,x\}$, and if it contains $\{0,x\}$, it's an open neighbourhood of $x$.

Now, the sequence converges to $x$ iff every neighbourhood of $x$ contains all but finitely $x_n$ from the sequence. So it cannot converge to any $x \neq 2$, as in that case the neighbourhood $\{0,x\}$ (which just equals $\{0\}$ for $x=0$) cannot contain any term $2$ from the sequence and this term occurs infinitely many times.

But it does converge to $2$: $\{0,2\}$, the minimal neighbourhood contains *all* terms of the sequence, so this holds for all neighbourhoods of $2$ as well.

(ii) In the usual topology, $[0,1]^3$ has the product topology, so a sequence converges iff the different component sequences converge. This also gives you the limit.

Comment: I don't understand the first sequence converge or not ?

Comment: Like I said, it converges to $2$, and not to any other point.

Comment: @Ripan Saha say that it does not converge, can you please explain me more because i still don't understand how we proceed ?thank you

Comment: @RipanSaha is wrong, it does converge to $2$: if $O$ is an open set that contains $2$, it also contains $0$ by the definition of the topology, so it contains all elements of the sequence, so we take $n_0 = 1$ in your definition, and are done.

Comment: but all neighbourhood of $l$ must contain element of the sequence !, please can you give me in general steps in order to if the sequence is  convergent or not, what is the first thing to do ?

Comment: Yes, every open set of the form $\{0,l\}, l \neq 2$,contains infinitely many elements of the sequence but also misses infinitely many elements of the sequence. So it cannot converge.

Comment: Start with: what does a neighbourhood of a point $l$ (a candidate limit) look like?

Comment: a neighborhood of $l$ look like $\{0,l\}$ or [0,l]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18842/discussion-between-vrouvrou-and-henno-brandsma).